# Kivy: get the root widget size

Tags: layout, canvas, widget, size, kivy

I want to get the size of the root widget so I can use it to calculate the size and position of child widget. Here's my simple code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class PictoGame(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        FloatLayout.__init__(self)
        self.add_widget(Button(text = "Button 1", size = (10,10)) ) 


class PictoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        my_game = PictoGame()
        print str(my_game.size)
        return my_game

PictoApp().run()
```

The size printed out is [1,1] ? What I see is big window, so can not be [1,1]
The button take full size of window, not (10,10) as I want.

There must be some concept of kivy I missed. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: I assume you want to calculate the size of the child widget(The button) so you can place and size it to your liking. This is not the way to go about it. You should go look at some of the tutorials on the kivy.org site.

Answer (score 0):

With kivy you shouldn't normally try to manually manage sizes like this - you can do it, but it's the harder way to go. Instead, use layouts to do the work for you.

I'd give an example, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

If you're certain you want to do everything manually, you can use Clock.schedule(some_function, 0) to schedule a function that sets the size and position to your liking. The Clock should only call it once the size of everything is determined.

Comment: What I tried is to get the actual size of the window. Which is now showing [1,1]

Comment: The window size is given by kivy.core.window.Window.size

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using size_hint_y, size_hint_x, and pos_hint?

```
Button:
    size_hint_x: .25
    size_hint_y: .1
    pos_hint: {'x': .375, 'y': .25}
```

this will help to automatically size and position your button according to the size of your window.

Answer (score 0):

The window size (as comment by @inclement on another answer) is in `kivy.core.window.Window.size`

A simple use is:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

...

window_width, window_height = Window.size
```

The variables `window_width` and `window_height` will get the size of the root window.